# selected chechbox when page in loading

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have `RoleClaimValue` Table in database , It haS `RoleID` and `ClaimValue` .

I want to when user enter the page pre-selection the checkbox.

I'm using this code in **HTML**:

```
<div *ngFor="let sub of subRoles" id="checkbox">
    <p-checkbox *ngIf="sub.rolelevel === role.id" selected="selectedSubRole" [value]="sub.id" [(ngModel)]="selectedSubRole" inputId="selectedSubRole" label="{{sub.description}}"></p-checkbox>
</div>
```

and I send the request from server and it return to me list of `ClaimValue`  .

```
GetRoleClaim(id:number){
    this.roleService.GetClaimsId(id).subscribe((data)=>{
        this.selectedSubRole=[...data]
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach((el)=>{
            this.selectedSubRole.push(el)
        })
        console.log('test ==>',this.selectedSubRole)
     })
 }
```

`this.selectedSubRole` file with list of `ClaimValue` .

`ClaimValue :["1006","1009","1006"]`

I am using this code but does not work and not pre-selection checkbox . 
What's the problem? how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What does this mean? 'this.selectedSubRole=[...data]' and after that: loop 'data' and 'this.selectedSubRole.push(el)'

Comment: r u need to checked the checkbox based on *ngIf="sub.rolelevel === role.id" condition

Comment: Does your this.selectedSubRole matches sub.id ([value]="sub.id")?

Comment: @RamAnji not . it not for this .

Comment: @ThomsheerAhamed they are not matched

Comment: -1 for not clarify what is data you got from roleService and when do you need your checkbox to be checked (based on received data from the shared services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on things I've noticed from your question, it can be:

```
export class AppComponent {
  value: boolean = true;
  subRoles : SubRole[] = []
  selectedSubRoles = [] ;

  role = {
    id: 1
  }

  constructor(){
    this.getSubRoles().subscribe(data => {
      this.subRoles = data;
    })
    this.GetRoleClaim(this.role.id);
  }

  getDatas(id):Observable<any>{
    return of([
        'val1',
        'val4',
        'val3'
      ]).pipe(delay(1000));
  }

  getSubRoles():Observable<any>{
    return of([
      {
        id: 'val1',
        rolelevel: 1,
        description: 'check 1'
      },
      {
        id: 'val2',
        rolelevel: 1,
        description: 'check 2'
      },
      {
        id: 'val3',
        rolelevel: 2,
        description: 'check 3'
      },
      {
        id: 'val4',
        rolelevel: 1,
        description: 'check 4'
      }
    ]).pipe(delay(1000));
  }

  GetRoleClaim(id:number){
    this.getDatas(id).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.selectedSubRoles = data
    this.subRoles.forEach((el , index)=>{
      el.checked = this.selectedSubRoles.some(e => el.id === e)
    })
    console.log(this.subRoles)
   });
  }
}

interface SubRole {
  id:string,
  rolelevel:number,
  description:string,
  checked ?:boolean
}
```

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let sub of subRoles" id="checkbox">
  <p-checkbox *ngIf="sub.rolelevel === role.id" 
              [(ngModel)]="sub.checked"
              binary="true" 
              label="{{sub.description}}"
            >
  </p-checkbox>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-p-checkbox-issue-qgl9ru).

tell me know if there is any problem.

Comment: did you check the demo and whats the problem?

Comment: problem => check box not checked

Comment: you want to 3 check boxes to be checked? your question is not clear enough, please explain what you want or it should be closed.

Comment: My question is absolutely clear. I want to choose the values that it takes from the database.

Comment: where and when do you get subRoles array?